# renaming shell script with regex

Tags: shell, loops, for-loop, rename

I'm trying to make a little shell script which renames all files which starts with `vlc-record*`.

So basically I've done some recordings with the vlc player but I don't like the chosen "title" so I'd like to snipe the first characters.

For example:

```
vlc-record-2013-01-18-01h14m49s-title_of_the_dj.mp3
```

I just want to rename it to:

```
title_of_the_dj.mp3
```

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Should probably ask this on unix and linux. Flagged it to be moved.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in vlc-record-*.mp3; do
  echo mv "$i" "${i##*-}"
done
```

If you like the commands it generates, remove the `echo` word and rerun the script.